# lwc navigateMixin specify fields

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-development

In my LWC component js file I have this code:

```
handleStudentSelected(event) {
        const defaultValues = encodeDefaultFieldValues({
            Tutor__c: this.tutorId,
            Student__c: event.detail
        });
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Time_Tracker__c',
                actionName: 'new'
            },
            state: {
                defaultFieldValues: defaultValues
            }
        });
```

this works very well BUT rather than showing all the `time_tracker__c` fields I only want to specify a subset of the fields.

Is this possible? or do I need to create a new component that shows the specified fields, then navigate to that either by creating an aura component for this or create a URL in Base64 encoded form.

here's what I'd like

```
handleStudentSelected(event) {
        const defaultValues = encodeDefaultFieldValues({
            Tutor__c: this.tutorId,
            Student__c: event.detail
        });
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Time_Tracker__c',
                actionName: 'new'
            },
            state: {
                defaultFieldValues: defaultValues
            }**,
            fields: {
                name, student__c, tutor__c, time__c, other__c
            }**
        });
```

---

***UPDATE******
I tried to implement this idea

````
<template>
    <template for:each={sts.data.records} for:item="st">
    <c-contact-tile 
        key={st.Id} 
        contact={st} 
        onselected={handleStudentSelected} 
        class="slds-var-m-around_x-small">
    </c-contact-tile>
    </template>
    <template if:true={modalVisible}>
    <lightning-quick-action-panel header={newModalHeader} class="center-modal">
       <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="TTracker__c" onsuccess={handleIt}>
          <lightning-input-field field-name="time__c"></lightning-input-field>
       </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </lightning-quick-action-panel>
    </template>
 </template>

```javascript
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
export default class stList extends LightningElement {
@track modalVisible = false;

handleStudentSelected(event) {
  modalVisible = true;
  st__c = event.detail;
}
}


BUT GET SCRIPT ERROR
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigation mixin can navigate you only to the standard create new record action.

If you want to display just some fields you should utilize `record-edit-form` and to display it in modal like way use `quick-action-panel`. Visibility of this modal can be toggled with `if:true`. Something like this.

```
<div if:true={modalVisible}>
    <lightning-quick-action-panel header={newModalHeader} class="center-modal">
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="ImpartnerMDF__FundsClaim__c" onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="ImpartnerMDF__FundsRequest__c" value={recordId}
                                   disabled></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input type="text" label="Payment Amount" required autocomplete="off" onchange={handleInputChange} name="ImpartnerMDF__PaymentAmount__c"></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="ImpartnerMDF__PaymentAmount__c" required class="display-none"></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="ImpartnerMDF__InvoiceNumber__c" required></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Invoice_Payee_Name__c" required></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Invoice_Date__c" required></lightning-input-field>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
        <div slot="footer">
            <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" onclick={handleCancelClick}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Create" class="slds-m-left_x-small"
                              onclick={handleCreateClick}></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-quick-action-panel>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
</div>
```

And this css class will make the modal centered and absolute on screen.

```
.center-modal {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 10001;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**figured it out**

````
<!-- sldsValidatorIgnore -->
<!-- sldsValidatorIgnore -->
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Students for this Tutor" icon-name="standard:calibration">
    </lightning-card>
    <div class="slds-card slds-var-p-around_x-small">
       <template if:true={students.data}>
          <template if:true={students.data.records.length}>
             <lightning-card title="">
                <p>
                   <lightning-formatted-text value="Please take a few moments to share how many hours you spent and how things went with your student in the last month. If you did not meet at all, please enter “0” in the number of tutoring hours."></lightning-formatted-text>
                </p>
                <p>
                   <lightning-formatted-text value="If you have multiple students you will fill out a separate page for each student."></lightning-formatted-text>
                </p>
                <p>
                   <lightning-formatted-text value="Additional data about each field can be found in the Help icon to the left of each field."></lightning-formatted-text>
                </p>
                <p>
                   <lightning-formatted-text value="There is no way to save your application midstream.  Please review all fields and ensure you have everything before you submit this form."></lightning-formatted-text>
                </p>
                <p>
                   <lightning-formatted-text value="If you have any questions, please contact your Match Advisor."> </lightning-formatted-text>
                </p>
             </lightning-card>
             <div class="content">
                <template for:each={students.data.records} for:item="student">
                   <c-contact-tile
                      key={student.Id}
                      contact={student}
                      draggable={tilesAreDraggable}
                      onselected={handleStudentSelected}
                      class="slds-var-m-around_x-small"
                      >
                   </c-contact-tile>
                </template>
             </div>
             <c-paginator
                page-number={pageNumber}
                page-size={students.data.pageSize}
                total-item-count={students.data.totalItemCount}
                onprevious={handlePreviousPage}
                onnext={handleNextPage}
                ></c-paginator>
          </template>
          <template if:false={students.data.records.length}>
             <c-placeholder
                message="There are no students matching your current selection"
                ></c-placeholder>
          </template>
       </template>
       <template if:true={students.error}>
          <c-error-panel errors={students.error}></c-error-panel>
       </template>
    </div>
    <div>
       <template if:true={modalVisible}>
          <lightning-quick-action-panel header={newModalHeader} class="center-modal">
             <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Time_Tracker__c" onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit ={handleSubmit}>
                <lightning-messages>
                </lightning-messages>
                <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true">
                   <lightning-layout-item class="slds-p-around_xx-small" size="12">
                      <lightning-layout>
                         <lightning-layout-item class="slds-p-around_xx-small" size=6>
                            <lightning-input-field field-name='Tutor__c' value={tutorId} disabled="true"></lightning-input-field>
                            <lightning-input-field field-name='Student__c' value={studentId} disabled="true"></lightning-input-field>
                         </lightning-layout-item>
                         <lightning-layout-item class="slds-p-around_xx-small" size=6>
                            <lightning-input-field field-name='Student_Hours__c'></lightning-input-field>
                            <lightning-input-field field-name='Teaching_Hours__c'></lightning-input-field>
                            <lightning-input-field field-name='Need_support_from_your_Match_Advisor__c'></lightning-input-field>
                         </lightning-layout-item>
                      </lightning-layout>
                      <div>
                         <lightning-layout>
                            <lightning-layout-item flexibility="grow">
                               <lightning-input-field field-name='Improvements_in_the_last_month__c'></lightning-input-field>
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                         </lightning-layout>
                      </div>
                      <lightning-layout>
                         <lightning-layout-item flexibility="grow">
                            <lightning-input-field field-name='Challenges_in_the_last_month__c'></lightning-input-field>
                         </lightning-layout-item>
                      </lightning-layout>
                   </lightning-layout-item>
                </lightning-layout>
                <div class="center">
                   <lightning-button variant="brand-outline" class="slds-m-top_small" label="Cancel" onclick={handleCancel}></lightning-button>
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <lightning-button variant="brand" class="slds-m-top_small" label="Save" type="submit"></lightning-button>
                </div>
             </lightning-record-edit-form>
          </lightning-quick-action-panel>
       </template>
    </div>
 </template>


```javascript

import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
// Lightning Message Service and message channels
import { subscribe, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import TUTOR_SELECTED_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/TutorSelected__c';

// fill array from Apex class
import getStudents from '@salesforce/apex/EIAController.getStudents';

/**
 * Container component that loads and displays a list of Student records.
 */
export default class StudentList extends LightningElement {
    /**
     * Whether to display the search bar.
     * TODO - normalize value because it may come as a boolean, string or otherwise.
     */
     @api searchBarIsVisible = false;

     /**
      * Whether the product tiles are draggable.
      * TODO - normalize value because it may come as a boolean, string or otherwise.
      */
     @api tilesAreDraggable = false;

    modalVisible = false;

    tutorId;
    studentId;
    /** Current page in the Student list. */
    pageNumber = 1;

    /** The number of items on a page. */
    pageSize;

    /** The total number of items matching the selection. */
    totalItemCount = 0;
 
    /** Load context for Lightning Messaging Service */
    @wire(MessageContext) 
    messageContext;

       /** Subscription for tutorsId Lightning message */
       tutorIdSubscription;

       @wire(getStudents, { tutorId: '$tutorId'})
       students;
    
    connectedCallback() {
        // Subscribe to TutorsFiltered message
        this.tutorIdSubscription = subscribe(
            this.messageContext,
            TUTOR_SELECTED_MESSAGE,
            (message) => this.handleTutorMessage(message)
        );
    }

    handleStudentSelected(event) {
        this.modalVisible = true;
        this.studentId = event.detail;        
    }

    handleSuccess(e) {
        // Close the modal window and display a success toast
        this.modalVisible =false;
        this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Record created!',
                variant: 'success'
            })
        );

   }
   handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log('onsubmit event recordEditForm '+ JSON.stringify(event.detail.fields));
    }

    handleCancel(event) {
        // Close the modal window 
        this.modalVisible =false;
        this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
    }
    
    handleTutorMessage(message) {
        this.tutorId = message.tutorId ;
    }

    handlePreviousPage() {
        this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber - 1;
    }

    handleNextPage() {
        this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber + 1;
    }
}
````